# how to make a header image with text and a logo on top of the header image?

Tags: html, css, image, header

im trying to make a header image for my website that will allow me to display the logo and text that i have already used in my website over it and the image in the background if you will.

the html code is as follows:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title> The World Traveller </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
```

```
<div id="wrapper";>

<header>
    <h2 class="logo"> logo here </h2>
    <h1> The World traveller </h1>
</header>
```

And the main css file contains this :

```
body {
background-color:#696969;
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family:"Arial" san-serif;
}



.logo{
text-indent: -99999px;
background: url("logo2.jpg");
width: 200px;
height:170px;
margin:0;
}

header {
background-image:dodgeblue;
padding:0 0 15px;

background-color:#4682B4;
padding: 40px 0;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
```

im not sure what to do and would love some help thank you. :) 
if i need to put more of my code on here let me know.

Comment: Can you little more specific how logo and text should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Change your header to this.

```
<header>
<img src class="logo"> 
<h1> The World traveller </h1>
</header
```

and you need to change your logo class to say background-image not just background.

```
.logo{
text-indent: -99999px;
background-image: url("logo2.jpg");
width: 200px;
height:170px;
margin:0;
}
```

also you have

```
header {
background-image:dodgeblue;
padding:0 0 15px;
background-color:#4682B4;
padding: 40px 0;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
```

dodgeblue isn't an image I would delete that since you already have a background color.